# Is there any way to handle mutiple dataSource on same graph using devExpress charts

Tags: angular, devexpress

I Need to show the graph with three different dataSources. I need to show all the three or any two or one dataSource on same graph. Each dataSource values differ on their way with no y-axis value but with x-axis as dateTime.
Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code with random generated values of three different dataSources. The code for html and ts files is in below mentioned code block.

HTML Code

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <label class="checkbox-inline text-danger"><input type="checkbox" checked (click)="showOne()"><b> Audio</b></label> 
    <label class="checkbox-inline text-success"><input type="checkbox" checked (click)="showTwo()"><b> Frozen</b></label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline text-info"><input type="checkbox" checked (click)="showThree()"><b> Color</b></label>
</div>
   <div id="popup">
        <dx-chart id="chart" [dataSource]="devGraphData" 
        [animation]="false" 
        zoomingMode="all" scrollingMode="all">
        <dxo-size [height]="300"></dxo-size>
        <dxi-value-axis [valueMarginsEnabled]="true" >
        <dxo-grid [visible]="false"></dxo-grid></dxi-value-axis>
        <dxi-series type="area" valueField="value1" name="data1" color="red"><dxo-point [visible] = false></dxo-point></dxi-series>
        <dxi-series valueField="value2" name="data2" color="green"><dxo-point [visible] = true symbol="triangleDown"></dxo-point></dxi-series>
        <dxi-series valueField="value3" name="data" color="blue"><dxo-point [visible] = true></dxo-point></dxi-series>
        <dxo-common-series-settings argumentField="index" type="line" tagField="data"></dxo-common-series-settings>
        <dxo-argument-axis [valueMarginsEnabled]="false"></dxo-argument-axis>
        <dxo-tooltip [enabled]="true"></dxo-tooltip>
        <dxo-legend [visible]="false"></dxo-legend>
        <dxo-scroll-bar [visible]="true"></dxo-scroll-bar>
        </dx-chart>
    </div>
```

ts code

```
export class MultiChartComponent {
    devGraphData: MultiChartComponent[] = [];
    devGraphData1: MultiChartComponent[] = [];
    devGraphData2: MultiChartComponent[] = [];
    devGraphData3: MultiChartComponent[] = [];
    devGraphIndex: number = 0;
    devGraphIndex2: number = 0;
    devGraphIndex3: number = 0;
    devData: any;
    firstChart: boolean = false;
    secondChart: boolean = false;
    thirdChart: boolean = false;

    constructor(public globalService:GlobalService) {
        Observable.interval(3000).subscribe(x => {
            this.getData(0,1);
        });
        Observable.interval(3000).subscribe(x => {
            this.getData(2,3);
        });
        Observable.interval(3000).subscribe(x => {
            this.getData(4,5);
        });
        this.showOne();
        this.showTwo();
        this.showThree();
    }

    public getData(minValue: any, maxValue: any) {
        this.devGraphIndex = this.devGraphIndex + 1;
        if (minValue === 0 && maxValue === 1) {
            this.devData = { 'index': this.devGraphIndex, 'value1': this.getRandomInt(minValue, maxValue)};
            this.devGraphData1.push(this.devData);
            this.concatArrays();
            if(this.devGraphData1.length > 50) {
                this.devGraphData1.splice(0, 1);
            }
        }
        if (minValue === 2 && maxValue === 3) {
            this.devData = { 'index': this.devGraphIndex, 'value2': this.getRandomInt(minValue, maxValue) };
            this.devGraphData2.push(this.devData);
            this.concatArrays();
            if(this.devGraphData2.length > 50) {
                this.devGraphData2.splice(0, 1);
            }
        }
        if (minValue === 4 && maxValue === 5) {
            this.devData = { 'index': this.devGraphIndex, 'value3': this.getRandomInt(minValue, maxValue) };
            this.devGraphData3.push(this.devData);
            this.concatArrays();
            if(this.devGraphData3.length > 50) {
                this.devGraphData3.splice(0, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public getRandomInt(min:any, max:any) {
        return Math.abs(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    public showOne() {
        this.devGraphData = [];
        if (this.firstChart === true) {
             this.firstChart = false;
        } else {
            this.firstChart = true;
        }
        this.concatArrays();
    }

    public showTwo() {
        this.devGraphData = [];
        if (this.secondChart === true) {
             this.secondChart = false;
        } else {
            this.secondChart = true;
        }
        this.concatArrays();
    }

    public showThree() {
        this.devGraphData = [];
        if (this.thirdChart === true) {
             this.thirdChart = false;
        } else {
            this.thirdChart = true;
        }
        this.concatArrays();
    }

    public concatArrays() {
        if(this.firstChart === true && this.secondChart === true && this.thirdChart === true) {
            this.devGraphData = this.devGraphData2.concat(this.devGraphData3);
            this.devGraphData = this.devGraphData.concat(this.devGraphData1);
        } else if(this.firstChart === true && this.secondChart === true) {
            this.devGraphData = this.devGraphData1.concat(this.devGraphData2);
        } else if(this.secondChart === true && this.thirdChart === true) {
            this.devGraphData = this.devGraphData2.concat(this.devGraphData3);
        } else if(this.firstChart === true && this.thirdChart === true) {
            this.devGraphData = this.devGraphData1.concat(this.devGraphData3);
        } else if(this.firstChart === true) {
            this.devGraphData = this.devGraphData.concat(this.devGraphData1);
        } else if(this.secondChart === true) {
            this.devGraphData = this.devGraphData.concat(this.devGraphData2);
        } else if(this.thirdChart === true) {
            this.devGraphData = this.devGraphData.concat(this.devGraphData3);
        }
    } 
}
```